# Multiple Regression in PHP

Tags: php, regression, linear-regression

I need to run a multiple regression however, I can't find any libraries in PHP that supports this. I need to regress a dependent variable (y) against several independent variables (x1, x2, x3, etc.)

The formula would look something along the lines of this:

> Y = a1x1 + a2x2 + a3x3 + c

Where a1, a2 and a3 are weights assigned to the different variables.

Answer (score 3):

I know it's probably too late to a answering this question, but I was looking for the same thing and found this linear multivariate regression on GitHub: [PHP-Multivariate-Regression](https://github.com/carbocation/PHP-Multivariate-Regression)

Comment: Never is too late for answering such a question :-). The link you had provided is excellent.

Answer (score 1):

There is a polynomial regression library in PHP. You could use it for multiple regression.
http://polynomialregression.drque.net/